# rewrite a controller that is already rewriting another

Tags: overrides, controllers

Is it possible to rewrite a controller in a community module that is already rewriting a core controller?

I have the syntax correct as it is working in other rewrites but in this specific case the rewrite is not working.

There is a community module rewriting the cart controller and i want to rewrite the community modules cart controller.

It would be like this:

```
My Controller -> Community Modules cart controller -> Mage Cart controller
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may depend on how the extension is overriding the controller but here goes. You need to add in your module's `config.xml` file, this as a child of the `<config>` node.

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Your_ModuleNameHere before="Community_ModuleNameHere">Your_ModuleNameHere</Your_ModuleNameHere>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

If the community module overrides the cart controller in the same way as described above then it works. If it uses the 'old method' with `<from>` and `<to>` tags then it won't work.
(and I have no idea on how to override that).

**[EDIT]**
Make sure that your controller is also named `CartController` and it's located in `Namespace/Module/controllers/CartController.php`. Also you might want to make your local module depend on the community module but I don't think this is mandatory. Also make your controller class extend the community module controller.

Comment: this is precicely what is happening but it will not work.  How would one normally debug this?

Comment: @MartyWallace. I've just tested and it works. But see my update to the answer.